# Can you get the default folder open/closed icons from the system without an actual path?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, filesystems, icons

I already know how to get file-system-related icons for specific paths by P/Invoking to `SHGetFileInfo`.  But that requires an actual path.  Plus, it only returns a single icon.

What I'm wondering is two-fold.

1. How one would get both the default folder open and closed icons (I believe they are stored in 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\imageres.dll' or '%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll' but I could be wrong)
2. How to get those icons without actually specifying a path (i.e. via a constant or similar.)

Is there even such a way or am I going to have to simply pass it a 'dummy' path to `SHGetFileInfo` and forget about having two states?

For reference, I'm seeking this because we're building a custom tree to display certain file system objects, but they will be displayed underneath a few app-defined groups and we want those groups to resemble the same graphical folders as those used for actual directories.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can.

> **Disclaimer** (TL,DR) :
>   Don't get mad at me for the length of this answer. 98%
>   of it is just plain enumeration code you only have to copy paste
>   (I just like having everything at the same place and time)

Note that icon manipulations in the System.Drawing Namespace are known to be prone to **memory leaks**. I don't understand why no changes has been done through the years in the usage of `DestroyIcon(handle)` (which will aswell invalidate your icon down to a zero sized 0x0 icon), while you're supposed to use that very icon elsewhere in the code...

> *... Plus, it only returns a single icon...*

There is not a single method, managed or unmanaged I know of, that returns an icon with more than one single format and size. To have different icons, you'll have to invoke them one by one, or create each one of them by parsing the file containing the icons variations.

By the way, I'm just an amateur programmer that happended to have searched ways to debunk this whole Icon mess. What I wrote here is beginner level. Feel free to correct any mistake I made (I'm sure there are). I'm just amazed how difficult it is to find answers for UI tasks involving icons.

---

Take a look at [PInvoke/SHGetStockIconInfo](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/SHGetStockIconInfo.html)

Basically, you'll have to :

- create a `SHSTOCKICONID` structure
- Initialize its Size
- Call **`SHGetStockIconInfo(...)`** with this structure, the folder icon ID (enum member) and the icon options

And you get a pointer to the icon you're looking for, among the stock icons of the system (Folder Icon included)

By the way, the method also provides you (through the structure, if properly initialized) usefull information, such as the path to the file containing the system icon, and its index in that file, but since you already have the pointer to the icon, all you have to do is create an icon :

```
Icon icon = Icon.FromHandle(handle)
// And here is where you don't really know how to destroy the handle...
```

> **CAUTION !!!**
>   The API and some enum values doesn't work on some
>   platforms. Simply put, everything before Windows Vista has little to
>   no support at all. Furthermore, almost everything is for Desktop
>   Applications only ! By the way, things may not work on Windows CE.
>
> Windows 7 and above has extended capabilities that are not covered by
>   this answer.
>
> Known alternative to API calls : WPF and VectorIcons. Not covered here.

---

Use the following Namespaces :

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; // [DllImport()], [MarshalAs()]
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices // [Extension()]
```

A very important declaration to begin with : the **`DestroyIcon()`** method.

```
/// <summary>
/// Destroys an icon and frees any memory the icon occupied.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hIcon">A handle to the icon to be destroyed. The icon must not be in use.</param>
/// <returns>If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero. If the function fails, the return value is zero.</returns>
/// <remarks>To get extended error information, call GetLastError.</remarks>
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "DestroyIcon", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr hIcon);
```

So, here is your `Shell32` declaration (courtesy of PInvoke, XML comments added) :

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieves information about a stock icon.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="siid">One of the values from the SHSTOCKICONID enumeration that specifies which icon should be retrieved.</param>
/// <param name="uFlags">A combination of zero or more of the following flags that specify which information is requested.</param>
/// <param name="psii">A pointer to a SHSTOCKICONINFO structure. When this function is called, the cbSize member of this structure needs to be set to the size of the SHSTOCKICONINFO structure. When this function returns, contains a pointer to a SHSTOCKICONINFO structure that contains the requested information.</param>
/// <returns>If this function succeeds, it returns S_OK. Otherwise, it returns an HRESULT error code.</returns>
/// <remarks>If this function returns an icon handle in the hIcon member of the SHSTOCKICONINFO structure pointed to by psii, you are responsible for freeing the icon with DestroyIcon when you no longer need it.</remarks>
[DllImport("Shell32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
private static extern Int32 SHGetStockIconInfo(SHSTOCKICONID siid, SHGSI uFlags, ref SHSTOCKICONINFO psii);
```

Here is how the `SHSTOCKICONINFO` structure looks like (XML comments added) :

```
/// <summary>
/// Receives information used to retrieve a stock Shell icon. This structure is used in a call SHGetStockIconInfo.
/// </summary>
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct SHSTOCKICONINFO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The size of this structure, in bytes.
    /// </summary>
    public UInt32 cbSize;
    /// <summary>
    /// When SHGetStockIconInfo is called with the SHGSI_ICON flag, this member receives a handle to the icon.
    /// </summary>
    public IntPtr hIcon;
    /// <summary>
    /// When SHGetStockIconInfo is called with the SHGSI_SYSICONINDEX flag, this member receives the index of the image in the system icon cache.
    /// </summary>
    public Int32 iSysIconIndex;
    /// <summary>
    /// When SHGetStockIconInfo is called with the SHGSI_ICONLOCATION flag, this member receives the index of the icon in the resource whose path is received in szPath.
    /// </summary>
    public Int32 iIcon;
    /// <summary>
    /// When SHGetStockIconInfo is called with the SHGSI_ICONLOCATION flag, this member receives the path of the resource that contains the icon. The index of the icon within the resource is received in iIcon.
    /// </summary>
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAX_PATH)]
    public string szPath;
}
```

Because **`MAX_PATH`** in the `SHSTOCKICONINFO` structure is not defined, here it is :

```
const Int32 MAX_PATH = 260;
```

**`SHGSI`** is an enumeration to define the options you want to submit along with your call to `SHGetStockIconInfo()`

```
/// <summary>
/// UInt Enumeration with Flags that specify which information is requested.
/// </summary>
[Flags()]
public enum SHGSI : UInt32
{

    /// <summary>
    /// The szPath and iIcon members of the SHSTOCKICONINFO structure receive the path and icon index of the requested icon, in a format suitable for passing to the ExtractIcon function. The numerical value of this flag is zero, so you always get the icon location regardless of other flags.
    /// </summary>
    SHGSI_ICONLOCATION = 0,

    /// <summary>
    /// The hIcon member of the SHSTOCKICONINFO structure receives a handle to the specified icon.
    /// </summary>
    SHGSI_ICON = 0x100,

    /// <summary>
    /// The iSysImageImage member of the SHSTOCKICONINFO structure receives the index of the specified icon in the system imagelist.
    /// </summary>
    SHGSI_SYSICONINDEX = 0x4000,

    /// <summary>
    /// Modifies the SHGSI_ICON value by causing the function to add the link overlay to the file's icon.
    /// </summary>
    SHGSI_LINKOVERLAY = 0x8000,

    /// <summary>
    /// Modifies the SHGSI_ICON value by causing the function to blend the icon with the system highlight color.
    /// </summary>
    SHGSI_SELECTED = 0x10000,

    /// <summary>
    /// Modifies the SHGSI_ICON value by causing the function to retrieve the large version of the icon, as specified by the SM_CXICON and SM_CYICON system metrics.
    /// </summary>
    SHGSI_LARGEICON = 0x0,

    /// <summary>
    /// Modifies the SHGSI_ICON value by causing the function to retrieve the small version of the icon, as specified by the SM_CXSMICON and SM_CYSMICON system metrics.
    /// </summary>
    SHGSI_SMALLICON = 0x1,

    /// <summary>
    /// Modifies the SHGSI_LARGEICON or SHGSI_SMALLICON values by causing the function to retrieve the Shell-sized icons rather than the sizes specified by the system metrics.
    /// </summary>
    SHGSI_SHELLICONSIZE = 0x4

}
```

`SHSTOCKICONID` is an enumeration with LOTs of values. Hope you won't have that much headache... :P - Please, take a ride over [MSDN constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of this Enumeration to get an idea of how the icons look like.

```
/// <summary>
/// Used by SHGetStockIconInfo to identify which stock system icon to retrieve.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>SIID_INVALID, with a value of -1, indicates an invalid SHSTOCKICONID value.</remarks>
public enum SHSTOCKICONID : UInt32
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Document of a type with no associated application.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_DOCNOASSOC = 0,
    /// <summary>
    /// Document of a type with an associated application.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_DOCASSOC = 1,
    /// <summary>
    /// Generic application with no custom icon.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_APPLICATION = 2,
    /// <summary>
    /// Folder (generic, unspecified state).
    /// </summary>
    SIID_FOLDER = 3,
    /// <summary>
    /// Folder (open).
    /// </summary>
    SIID_FOLDEROPEN = 4,
    /// <summary>
    /// 5.25-inch disk drive.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_DRIVE525 = 5,
    /// <summary>
    /// 3.5-inch disk drive.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_DRIVE35 = 6,
    /// <summary>
    /// Removable drive.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_DRIVEREMOVE = 7,
    /// <summary>
    /// Fixed drive (hard disk).
    /// </summary>
    SIID_DRIVEFIXED = 8,
    /// <summary>
    /// Network drive (connected).
    /// </summary>
    SIID_DRIVENET = 9,
    /// <summary>
    /// Network drive (disconnected).
    /// </summary>
    SIID_DRIVENETDISABLED = 10,
    /// <summary>
    /// CD drive.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_DRIVECD = 11,
    /// <summary>
    /// RAM disk drive.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_DRIVERAM = 12,
    /// <summary>
    /// The entire network.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_WORLD = 13,
    /// <summary>
    /// A computer on the network.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_SERVER = 15,
    /// <summary>
    /// A local printer or print destination.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_PRINTER = 16,
    /// <summary>
    /// The Network virtual folder (FOLDERID_NetworkFolder/CSIDL_NETWORK).
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MYNETWORK = 17,
    /// <summary>
    /// The Search feature.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_FIND = 22,
    /// <summary>
    /// The Help and Support feature.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_HELP = 23,

// OVERLAYS...

    /// <summary>
    /// Overlay for a shared item.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_SHARE = 28,
    /// <summary>
    /// Overlay for a shortcut.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_LINK = 29,
    /// <summary>
    /// Overlay for items that are expected to be slow to access.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_SLOWFILE = 30,

// MORE ICONS...

    /// <summary>
    /// The Recycle Bin (empty).
    /// </summary>
    SIID_RECYCLER = 31,
    /// <summary>
    /// The Recycle Bin (not empty).
    /// </summary>
    SIID_RECYCLERFULL = 32,
    /// <summary>
    /// Audio CD media.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIACDAUDIO = 40,
    /// <summary>
    /// Security lock.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_LOCK = 47,
    /// <summary>
    /// A virtual folder that contains the results of a search.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_AUTOLIST = 49,
    /// <summary>
    /// A network printer.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_PRINTERNET = 50,
    /// <summary>
    /// A server shared on a network.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_SERVERSHARE = 51,
    /// <summary>
    /// A local fax printer.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_PRINTERFAX = 52,
    /// <summary>
    /// A network fax printer.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_PRINTERFAXNET = 53,
    /// <summary>
    /// A file that receives the output of a Print to file operation.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_PRINTERFILE = 54,
    /// <summary>
    /// A category that results from a Stack by command to organize the contents of a folder.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_STACK = 55,
    /// <summary>
    /// Super Video CD (SVCD) media.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIASVCD = 56,
    /// <summary>
    /// A folder that contains only subfolders as child items.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_STUFFEDFOLDER = 57,
    /// <summary>
    /// Unknown drive type.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_DRIVEUNKNOWN = 58,
    /// <summary>
    /// DVD drive.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_DRIVEDVD = 59,
    /// <summary>
    /// DVD media.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIADVD = 60,
    /// <summary>
    /// DVD-RAM media.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIADVDRAM = 61,
    /// <summary>
    /// DVD-RW media.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIADVDRW = 62,
    /// <summary>
    /// DVD-R media.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIADVDR = 63,
    /// <summary>
    /// DVD-ROM media.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIADVDROM = 64,
    /// <summary>
    /// CD+ (enhanced audio CD) media.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIACDAUDIOPLUS = 65,
    /// <summary>
    /// CD-RW media.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIACDRW = 66,
    /// <summary>
    /// CD-R media.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIACDR = 67,
    /// <summary>
    /// A writeable CD in the process of being burned.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIACDBURN = 68,
    /// <summary>
    /// Blank writable CD media.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIABLANKCD = 69,
    /// <summary>
    /// CD-ROM media.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIACDROM = 70,
    /// <summary>
    /// An audio file.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_AUDIOFILES = 71,
    /// <summary>
    /// An image file.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_IMAGEFILES = 72,
    /// <summary>
    /// A video file.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_VIDEOFILES = 73,
    /// <summary>
    /// A mixed (media) file.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MIXEDFILES = 74,


    /// <summary>
    /// Folder back. Represents the background Fold of a Folder.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_FOLDERBACK = 75,
    /// <summary>
    /// Folder front. Represents the foreground Fold of a Folder.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_FOLDERFRONT = 76,
    /// <summary>
    /// Security shield.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Use for UAC prompts only. This Icon doesn't work on all purposes.</remarks>
    SIID_SHIELD = 77,
    /// <summary>
    /// Warning (Exclamation mark).
    /// </summary>
    SIID_WARNING = 78,
    /// <summary>
    /// Informational (Info).
    /// </summary>
    SIID_INFO = 79,
    /// <summary>
    /// Error (X).
    /// </summary>
    SIID_ERROR = 80,
    /// <summary>
    /// Key.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_KEY = 81,
    /// <summary>
    /// Software.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_SOFTWARE = 82,
    /// <summary>
    /// A UI item, such as a button, that issues a rename command.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_RENAME = 83,
    /// <summary>
    /// A UI item, such as a button, that issues a delete command.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_DELETE = 84,
    /// <summary>
    /// Audio DVD media.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIAAUDIODVD = 85,
    /// <summary>
    /// Movie DVD media.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIAMOVIEDVD = 86,
    /// <summary>
    /// Enhanced CD media.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIAENHANCEDCD = 87,
    /// <summary>
    /// Enhanced DVD media.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIAENHANCEDDVD = 88,
    /// <summary>
    /// Enhanced DVD media.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIAHDDVD = 89,
    /// <summary>
    /// High definition DVD media in the Blu-ray Disc™ format.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIABLURAY = 90,
    /// <summary>
    /// Video CD (VCD) media.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIAVCD = 91,
    /// <summary>
    /// DVD+R media.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIADVDPLUSR = 92,
    /// <summary>
    /// DVD+RW media.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIADVDPLUSRW = 93,
    /// <summary>
    /// A desktop computer.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_DESKTOPPC = 94,
    /// <summary>
    /// A mobile computer (laptop).
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MOBILEPC = 95,
    /// <summary>
    /// The User Accounts Control Panel item.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_USERS = 96,
    /// <summary>
    /// Smart media.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIASMARTMEDIA = 97,
    /// <summary>
    /// CompactFlash media.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIACOMPACTFLASH = 98,
    /// <summary>
    /// A cell phone.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_DEVICECELLPHONE = 99,
    /// <summary>
    /// A digital camera.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_DEVICECAMERA = 100,
    /// <summary>
    /// A digital video camera.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_DEVICEVIDEOCAMERA = 101,
    /// <summary>
    /// An audio player.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_DEVICEAUDIOPLAYER = 102,
    /// <summary>
    /// Connect to network.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_NETWORKCONNECT = 103,
    /// <summary>
    /// The Network and Internet Control Panel item.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_INTERNET = 104,
    /// <summary>
    /// A compressed file with a .zip file name extension.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_ZIPFILE = 105,
    /// <summary>
    /// The Additional Options Control Panel item.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_SETTINGS = 106,
    /// <summary>
    /// Windows Vista with Service Pack 1 (SP1) and later. High definition DVD drive (any type - HD DVD-ROM, HD DVD-R, HD-DVD-RAM) that uses the HD DVD format.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_DRIVEHDDVD = 132,
    /// <summary>
    /// Windows Vista with SP1 and later. High definition DVD drive (any type - BD-ROM, BD-R, BD-RE) that uses the Blu-ray Disc format.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_DRIVEBD = 133,
    /// <summary>
    /// Windows Vista with SP1 and later. High definition DVD-ROM media in the HD DVD-ROM format.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIAHDDVDROM = 134,
    /// <summary>
    /// Windows Vista with SP1 and later. High definition DVD-R media in the HD DVD-R format.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIAHDDVDR = 135,
    /// <summary>
    /// Windows Vista with SP1 and later. High definition DVD-RAM media in the HD DVD-RAM format.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIAHDDVDRAM = 136,
    /// <summary>
    /// Windows Vista with SP1 and later. High definition DVD-ROM media in the Blu-ray Disc BD-ROM format.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIABDROM = 137,
    /// <summary>
    /// Windows Vista with SP1 and later. High definition write-once media in the Blu-ray Disc BD-R format.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIABDR = 138,
    /// <summary>
    /// Windows Vista with SP1 and later. High definition read/write media in the Blu-ray Disc BD-RE format.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MEDIABDRE = 139,
    /// <summary>
    /// Windows Vista with SP1 and later. A cluster disk array.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_CLUSTEREDDRIVE = 140,

    /// <summary>
    /// The highest valid value in the enumeration. Values over 160 are Windows 7-only icons.
    /// </summary>
    SIID_MAX_ICONS = 175
}
```

---

**Here we go !**

Create an utility wrapper. Class names and members vary, depending on your requirements. Here are how I've done it, but feel free to make all necessary edits :

```
public class IconUtils
{
    // copy DLL declarations above here...
    // ...

    // and copy again the XML summary here.
    public static bool DestroyIconH(IntPtr iconHandle)
    {
        return DestroyIcon(iconHandle);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Pointer to the (stock) Icon associated to the specified ID.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="StockIconID">Icon ID among the defined Stock ones.</param>
    /// <returns>The Pointer to the retrieved Icon. If no Icon were found, an empty Pointer is returned.</returns>
    private static IntPtr GetShellIconPointer(SHSTOCKICONID StockIconID, SHGSI IconOptions)
    {
        SHSTOCKICONINFO StkIconInfo = new SHSTOCKICONINFO();
        StkIconInfo.cbSize = Convert.ToUInt32(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SHSTOCKICONINFO)));

        if (SHGetStockIconInfo(StockIconID, IconOptions, StkIconInfo) == 0) {
            return StkIconInfo.hIcon;
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the (stock) Icon associated to the specified ID.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="StockIconID">Icon ID among the defined Stock ones.</param>
    /// <returns>The (stock) Icon. If no Icon were found, Null is returned.</returns>
    /// <remarks>WARNING ! Caller is responsible of calling Dispose() on the returned Icon.</remarks>
    public static Icon GetSystemIcon(SHSTOCKICONID stockIconID, SHGSI iconOptions)
    {
        IntPtr iconPointer = GetShellIconPointer(stockIconID, iconOptions);

        if (iconPointer != IntPtr.Zero) {
            Icon actualIcon = Icon.FromHandle(iconPointer);
            Icon iconCopy = (System.Drawing.Icon)actualIcon.Clone();

            actualIcon.Dispose();
            DestroyIcon(iconPointer);
            /*
                Honestly, I'm unsure of what I'm doing here :-(
                If I get rid of either actualIcon or iconCopy, 
                and don't make a copy of it, I get a 0x0 Icon.
                If I don't call DestroyIcon(h), I get a memory leak.
                I highly doubt a memory leak won't occur even with the trick above,
                but heh! >:-D honestly I don't care since 
                everything related to Icon retrieval in Windows 
                appears to me a very bad design pattern in the first place.
            */

            return iconCopy;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Also create an extension method for `System.Drawing.Bitmap`. The default CreateThumbnail() doesn't suits my needs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a Thumbnail of the Bitmap.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sourceBitmap">Source Bitmap.</param>
/// <param name="width">Width for the Tumbnail.</param>
/// <param name="height">Height for the Tumbnail.</param>
/// <returns>Returns the created Thumbnail.</returns>
[Extension()]
public Bitmap CreateThumbnail(this Bitmap sourceBitmap, Int32 width, Int32 height)
{
    if (sourceBitmap == null) {
        return null; // Eat Exception !
    } else {
        if ((width > 0) && (height > 0)) {
            Rectangle layoutRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
            Bitmap thumbnailBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, sourceBitmap.PixelFormat);

            using (Graphics bmpGrphics = thumbnailBitmap.CreateGraphics()) {
                bmpGrphics.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, layoutRectangle);
            }

            return thumbnailBitmap;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**How it works:**

Somewhere in your code, you use the utility wrapper with :

1. The icon ID you're looking for (one of `SHSTOCKICONID` values)
2. The options that fits the context.

This is the calls :

```
// You're looking for a 16x16 opened folder icon :
Icon icon16 = IconUtils.GetShellIcon(SHSTOCKICONID.SIID_FOLDEROPEN, SHGSI.SHGSI_ICON Or SHGSI.SHGSI_SMALLICON);

// You're looking for a 32x32 default state folder icon :
Icon icon32 = IconUtils.GetShellIcon(SHSTOCKICONID.SIID_FOLDER, SHGSI.SHGSI_ICON Or SHGSI.SHGSI_LARGEICON);
```

The PInvoke link above advises you to use `SHGSI.SHGSI_SMALLICON Or SHGSI.SHGSI_LARGEICON`, but that won't work (at least on my system). It seems failing to pass the SHGSI_ICON flag will prevent the icon handle from being correctly set in the structure. And I get no icon at all.

---

Oh ! By the way, in Windows 7 (which I use), `SHSTOCKICONID.SIID_FOLDER` and `SHSTOCKICONID.SIID_FOLDEROPEN` are represented by the **exact same icon**. MS FAIL IMHO ! Sometimes, I just use `SHSTOCKICONID.SIID_FOLDERBACK` to display a **closed** state, but you are free to select the one that suits your (and users) needs.

---

Extra :

Now you have the icons, I guess you want to use them somewhere, like storing them in two ImageList (`imgList16` and `imgList32` - or alike). Usually, you'll always have both 16x16 and 32x32 versions, returned in the format that suits your display (as advertised by MS). But I don't count on that, I always check I have both :

```
// Get the two icons...
Icon dirIcon16 = Icon_Class.GetShellIcon(SHSTOCKICONID.SIID_FOLDEROPEN, SHGSI.SHGSI_ICON | SHGSI.SHGSI_SMALLICON);
Icon dirIcon32 = Icon_Class.GetShellIcon(SHSTOCKICONID.SIID_FOLDEROPEN, SHGSI.SHGSI_ICON | SHGSI.SHGSI_LARGEICON);

// Make sure you have both...
if (DirIcon16 == null) {
    if (DirIcon32 == null) {
        // both are missing... use a placeholder bitmap instead.
        // do the necessary changes and checks...
    } else {
        // at least the 32x32 is available.
        Bitmap iconBitmap32 = dirIcon32.ToBitmap();
        Bitmap iconBitmap16 = iconBitmap32.CreateThumbnail(16, 16);
        // now you can add both in two ImageList...
        imgList16.Images.Add("Directory_Opened", iconBitmap16);
        imgList32.Images.Add("Directory_Opened", iconBitmap32);
        dirIcon32.Dispose();
    }
} else {
    Bitmap iconBitmap16 = dirIcon16.ToBitmap();
    imgList16.Images.Add("Directory_Opened", iconBitmap16);

    if (dirIcon32 == null) {
        Bitmap iconBitmap32 = iconBitmap16.CreateThumbnail(32, 32);

        imgList32.Images.Add("Directory_Opened", iconBitmap32);
    } else {
        Bitmap iconBitmap32 = dirIcon32.ToBitmap();

        imgList32.Images.Add("Directory_Opened", iconBitmap32);
        dirIcon32.Dispose();
    }

    dirIcon16.Dispose();
}
// hence the extension above.
```

---

As you can see, all this only provide you the 16x16 and 32x32 icons. That's a known limitation of Windows over the years. How applications (and several Windows Dialogs) are able to get other formats *is a completely different topic*. You can begin by using all the above to retrieve the path to the file containing the icon (either library, single icon, or executable) and its index in the resource. I advise you to play around with the `SHGSI` enumeration to retrieve those infos.

Then, you'll have to implement an **IconParser** after extracting the necessary Bytes or Stream, on your own (take care of non standard sized icons, consider icons larger than 255 pixels in size, wich won't have any valid width/height data in their header, beware of PNG compressed formats, caution negative values upon parsing chuncks, don't forget to release resources whenever possible, etc.)

<sub>Well, that said, I sucks at resource management... sorry :/</sub>

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to specify a dummy path when calling `SHGetFileInfo`. Set the pszPath parameter to something like `c:\foo`. Include `SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES` in the uFlags parameter along with your icon flags, this tells Windows that there is no real file to load (also include `SHGFI_OPENICON` to get the open folder). Include `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` in the dwFileAttributes parameter so Windows knows you want folder data.

See also:

- [What does SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES mean?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040601-00/?p=39073)
- [Why doesn’t SHGetFileInfo give me customized folder icons?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170501-00/?p=96075)